# Difference in behaviour between HTTP Status code 410 and other codes w.r.t Angular 5

Tags: java, angular, http, http-status-code-410

Backend: Java

Frontend: Angular 5

Consider this:

The frontend makes an HTTP request to the backend.

The backend returns an HTTP Status code as response to the frontend's request.

For error-handling testing, I change the HTTP code, returned from the backend, manually.

Scenario 1:

On setting the code-to-be-returned to FORBIDDEN (407), the frontend correctly displayed the 407 error. Now, on setting back the code to OK (200), the frontend correctly reflected that as well.

Scenario 2:

On setting the code-to-be-returned to GONE (410), the frontend correctly displayed the 410 error. However, on setting back the code to OK (200), the frontend **did not** correctly reflect the change, but continued to show error 410.

In fact, even after stopping the server, the frontend **did not** show a `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error, but continued to show the 410.

Any explanations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Be careful when using **`HTTP response status 410`**, since it will be cached in browser for indicating that the target resource is no longer available from the original server **and will not be available again**.(this is decided by server side). See **[details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/410)**.

Because it's server side who determine the expired period when response with `410`, so browser will simply cache it, and next time you try to request for the same resource, browser won't fire a request until it's expired. This can help for preventing useless requests.

Comment: Thanks! The first time this happened, it got resolved in a few minutes. However, now the 410 error is still being displayed (since a long time). Will clearing the browser's cache solve this? Is there any other method to solve it?

Comment: @RahulSaha I think you should response with **404** instead if the resource is not absolutely dead.

Comment: @RahulSaha have you tried restart your angular app and also maybe you also need to clear browser cache and restart the browser.

Comment: Clearing the cache worked! 

(Aside, I cleared the cache from chrome, but it did not reflect in my local folder, C:\Users\u1\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache,  - any idea why)?

Comment: Good anwser Sir !

Comment: I tried to solved it with `Cache-Control: no-cache` response header, but it did not work, use `no-store` instead;